# Why is my code telling me to initialize a variable that is already initialized?

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I have the below code:

```
public String palindrome(String str)
{
    String str, reverse = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = str.length();
    for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
    if (str.equals(reverse))
        System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
    else
        System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");

    return "";
}
```

It has an `init()` method that calls it when the character 'p' is typed and it is to check whether the current string is palindromic or not.

However ,when I compile it states there is an error in the line:

```
String str, reverse = "";
```

The error states that the variable may not have been initialized. However, when I initialize it another error message comes up stating that `str` has already been initialized.

Comment: Because `String str` is not initalized only `String reverse` is initalized to `EMPTYSTRING` but `str` is not initialized not even to null.

Comment: I would expect duplicate locale variable str...

Comment: You can't have a parameter and a variable withe the same name.

Comment: run this code .... you will get a NullPointerException.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat Nullponter ? how?
jack just initialize str like you did with reverse

Comment: int length = str.length(); .. must throw Nullpointer because it is not initialize.

Comment: Hey is it compilable ? You have method argument with name str and than creating local variable with same name

Comment: @NaveenRamawat He wouldn't get a `NullPointerException`, because his code wouldn't compile, even if he fixes the problem with the same parameter name.

Comment: @Tom Yes  I observed and replied the same in my next comment.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat You wrote *"must throw Nullpointer because it is not initialize"* which is wrong and then you wrote *"You have method argument with name str and than creating local variable with same name"* which is correct. But the first two comments are incorrect, even if OP wouldn't have the problem with the same name. Since he doesn't initialize `str` he can't get a `NullPointerException` from that, because the compiler would refuse to compile that.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your detailed response. Your are absolutely correct.

Comment: @NaveenRamawat No worries, you're welcome :).

Answer (score 2):

You have `str` duplicated, once as a parameter and once as a local variable. Besides that...

`String str, reverse = "";`

...does initialize `reverse` with "", but not `str`:

```
String str, reverse = "";
System.out.println(str); // error here "The local variable str may not have been initialized"
```

But...

```
String str = "", reverse = "";
System.out.println(str); // works fine
```

Comment: But this loses the parameter value, as you are re-referencing it

Comment: String str = "", reverse = "";

changing it to this doesnt fix it, however which one should i change in regards to the parameter and the local value being the same ?

Comment: No, you don't lose anything. As long as the parameter is (also) called `str`, the code doesn't even compile, because "Duplicate local variable str".

Comment: @Jack: Remove `str, `. It should simply read `String reverse = "";` No need for `str` there.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str, reverse = "";
```

this mean that reverse = "" and str is not initalized

```
String str = "" , reverse = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to declare str twice

```
  public String palindrome(String str)

  String str, reverse = "";
```

Almost certainly you did not intend to do that. Change it:

```
   String reverse = "";
```

It was that second str that was not being initialised

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize all the local variable in a method.You didnt initialize the variable str in your program .
you should have written like

String str="",reverse="";

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in function parameter too you have a `str`.

> **variable str is already defined in method palindrome(String)**

- Consider renaming of the parameter `str` or local variable `str` or
- simply remove the local variable since it **doesn't seem required** and parameter passed `str` would **suffice** for the required functionality.

Also, consider the following statement:

```
String str, reverse = "";
```

String `str` isn't initialized but only `reverse` is initialized to `""`(an empty string).

You may use:

```
 String str="", reverse = "";
```

Why do you have a return type as `String` as you are printing in the same function? Also, note it is simply returning `""` in either case.

```
public String palindrome(String str)
{
    String strTmp = "", reverse = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = str.length();
    for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
        reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
    if (str.equals(reverse)){
        strTmp = str;
        System.out.println("Entered string " + str + " is a palindrome.");
        }
    else
        System.out.println("Entered string " + str + " is not a palindrome.");

return strTmp;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Compiler is confused. Look at your code:

```
public String palindrome(String str)<-------- str as parameter 
{
 String str, reverse = "";  <-------- str as local variable [Also Not Initialized]
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int length = str.length(); <------------ Which str??? parameter or local Variable???
for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
if (str.equals(reverse)) <------------ Which str??? parameter or local Variable???
    System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
else
    System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
return "";
```

}

Change the name of your local variable or parameter and use accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your parameter variable and local variable are the same. So `str.length` is the local variable .

Simply you can change the local variable as `String str1=""` or `String str=""`
and you find no error.

Answer (score 0):

Rename local variable or palindrome method's parameter str.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    palindrome("hello");

}

public static String palindrome(String palindromeValue) {
    String str = palindromeValue, reverse = "";
    // Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = str.length();
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
    }
    if (str.equals(reverse)) {
        System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need a `String` `return type` as you're printing the value in the function itself.

Change you method declaration to `void`

```
public void palindrom(String str)
```

Your `String` `str` is already defined in your parameters.

> There is no need to define it again, just use it.

```
public void palindrome(String str)
    {
        String reverse = "";
        int length = str.length();
        for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
        if (str.equals(reverse))
            System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");
    }
```

**What happens if I declare the String again**

```
public void palindrome(String str)
{
  String str, reverse = "";
}
```

Your `str` variable is redefined here. The parameter value conflicts with the same name and your program won't compile.

Answer (score -1):

you are getting str as a argument and you are declaring it again